# Strange Ajax response in JSF ajax listener

Tags: html, ajax, jsf, primefaces

In one div, I've placed a form with two input texts and a button. When the user clicks on the button, the `createProject.register` method is called and the values of text fields are saved to a database table.

```
 <h:outputText id="opt" value="#{createProject.register}"></h:outputText>
 <h:commandButton value="Add URL">
       <f:ajax execute="@form" event="click" render="@form dt" listener="#{prTable.refresh}"></f:ajax>
       </h:commandButton>
```

Below the div, there's a datable with the ID dt. To refresh the data in the table, I've added `listener="#{prTable.refresh}"` to the `f:ajax` block. The refresh method in the PrTable class updates the arralylist of URLs. The datatable displays the list of URLs.

Problem: When I click on the button for the first time, the table is not refreshed. But, when I click the button 2nd time, the data table gets refreshed. The table doesn't display the current values in the input text field but it shows the values which were saved on the last button click.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you also post the code for the dataTable

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two different Beans for the table and form, I used one bean. At the end of the function which saved the data, I called the function which updated the ArrayList. I also removed outputtext and listener from the form. This solved my problem.